# Codeigniter 3: insert an email link with framework specific syntax doesn't work

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

In a Codeignieter 3 application I am making, I need to output some **email links** from the data base.

While `<a href="mailto:<?php echo $record->email; ?>"><?php echo $record->email; ?></a></td>` outputs `<a href="mailto:address@domain.com">address@domain.com</a>`

```
<?php echo anchor('mailto:' . $record->email, '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>', 'title="Email" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"'); ?>
```

outputs `<a href="http://localhost/cicrud/index.php/ddress@domain.com" title="Email" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>`

It adds the *base url* to the href attribute. How can I avoid this?

And how do I make a **phone link**, like `<a href="tel:0729.100.109">Call me</a>`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeIgnIter's **anchor** function is only for creating hyperlinks, for creating email links use **mailto** function.

Currently there is no such function to create telephone links, so you can use the below function **tel_link** as helper.

```
function tel_link($telno, $title = '', $attributes = ''){
    $title = (string) $title;
    if ($title === ''){
        $title = $telno;
    }
    return '<a href="tel:'.$telno.'"'._stringify_attributes($attributes).'>'.$title.'</a>';
}
```

Here is an example `echo tel_link('+91-1234567890', 'Click Here to Contact Me','class="tel_link"');`

Source : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#mailto

Comment: Great answer! What about making a phone link, like `<a href="tel:0729.100.109">Call me</a>`?

Comment: My phone numbers are stored in a varible: `$record->phone;`. Where shall I put the function before calling (using) it?

Comment: In codeigniter custom functions are added in files inside the **helpers** folder in application directory.
Refer this : [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a valid email link, use Codeigniters `mailto()` instead of `anchor()`

see more [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#mailto)

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` function automatically it takes your main url (site_url), as mention above `http://localhost/cicrud/index.php/` .

Below is the few example:

Please refer this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html .

You can use `mailto` of `safe_mailto` (for spam safe hyperlink) function.